# Android; notification while device is in sleep state

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I have a service that runs in the background that notifies to the status bar with a vibrate. However, when my phone goes into sleep state it no longer notifies with vibrates. How can I enable this functionality while the device is in sleep state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK). You can keep your service running while screen is off.
according to the developers doc, it's quite simple:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
..cpu will stay running on during this section..
wl.release();
```

In your case, if you want to keep your service always running, acquire your lock in `onStartCommand()` and release in `onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

First take care of the permissions (in the manifest file):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Then, most preferably use this in the Application file, or wherever:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "MyWakelockTag");
if(/*condition*/) {
    wakeLock.acquire(); //keep CPU awake
} else {
    wakeLock.release(); //disable keep CPU awake
}
```

Although it is a pretty cool feature, with great power comes great responsibility: It drains your battery life, hence use it responsibility.

I prefer to release this PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK by night as by base users do not use it beyond business hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **wake lock** follow this link:
[Keep the CPU on](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#cpu)

Here is how you set a wake lock directly

Kotlin:

```
val wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock =
        (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
            newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::MyWakelockTag").apply {
                acquire()
            }
        }
```

Java:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

To release the wake lock, both Java and Kotlin:

```
wakeLock.release()
```

Remember, to use a wake lock, the first step is to add the WAKE_LOCK permission to your application's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Or you also use a broadcast receiver that keeps the device awake
[Here is link](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#wakeful)